# xargs and git log --grep

Tags: git, xargs

I'm putting together a bash command to find Git commits from an old SVN repository. Here's my whole command:

```
$ svn log --xml --revision 323016 http://svn.php.net/repository | grep "<msg>" | sed 's/<msg>//' | xargs --verbose -i% git log --pretty=oneline --grep=\"%\"
git log --pretty=oneline --grep="Always restore PG(magic_quote_gpc) on request shutdown"
```

Running the first few parts of the command gives me the commit comment:

```
$ svn log --xml --revision 323016 http://svn.php.net/repository | grep "<msg>" | sed 's/<msg>//'
Always restore PG(magic_quote_gpc) on request shutdown
```

So that works fine - but then when I want to use git log --grep via xargs, it doesn't work (gives me no response).

Here's the weird part... `--verbose` prints out the command for me. If I copy and paste that exact command, I get the output I need. That is:

```
$ git log --pretty=oneline --grep="Always restore PG(magic_quote_gpc) on request shutdown"
87c038be06b8b0eb721270f98c858fd701f5d54b Always restore PG(magic_quote_gpc) on request shutdown
```

Also, this doesn't work for some reason:

```
$ echo -n "Always restore PG(magic_quote_gpc) on request shutdown" | xargs --verbose -i% git log --grep=\"%\"
git log --grep="Always restore PG(magic_quote_gpc) on request shutdown"
```

So it must be my usage of xargs, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would wrap the command that you are executing through xargs into sh

```
git rev-parse HEAD | xargs -n 1 -i{} sh -e "git log -1 {}"
```

I've used this to solve some escaping issues as well as executing complex scripts for each item that xargs passes:

```
git rev-parse HEAD | xargs -n 1 -i{} sh -e "some crazy looped code with {} embedded in multple places"
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're escaping the quotes.  I don't know WHY this is a problem, but I tried it, and the problem is definitely with the escaped quotes.  Somehow, when xargs invokes the command, it's making those quotes part of the argument so instead of searching for `Always restore PG(magic_quote_gpc) on request shutdown`, you're searching for `"Always restore PG(magic_quote_gpc) on request shutdown"`.  The following should work for you:

```
svn log --xml --revision 323016 http://svn.php.net/repository | grep "<msg>" | sed 's/<msg>//' | xargs --verbose -i% git log --pretty=oneline --grep="%"
```